# How do I pass my Google Analytics API response with webapp2

Tags: python, webapp2

I'm learning here so please be nice with me :)

Basically I'm trying to mix the Google Analytics hello world python tutorial with The Google App Engine Hello world python tutorial.

The Google Analytics python hello world ends with this :

```
def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The Google App Engine Hello world tutorial have something like this :

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')
```

My question is simple. How do I print the response of the Google Analytics script instead of the `Hello World` in the `class MainPage` function.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
import json


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
        report = get_report(analytics)
        data = json.dumps(report)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.write(data)
```